# How to change 'et al' to italic font in citation call-outs, with 'agsm' bibliography style

Tags: citing, natbib, italic, harvard-style

I am using `natbib` and `agsm` for harvard-style referencing. My related code is

```
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{agsm}
```

Then I am using `\citep{}` for citations. My problem is that in text I am getting

> (Author et al. 2012)

but and I want

> (Author *et al.* 2012)

Does anyone know how to change this and get 'et al' in italics in the text?

I am using TexPad and BibDesk and I have not been able to find the .bst files in Terminal.

I know that it is often correct to have the 'et al.' unitalicised but my university regulations requires italics.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please add the code of a *complete* document (starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`) to your post that illustrates the problem. Just use the [edit button](http://tex.stackexchange.com/posts/353858/edit).

Comment: Copy the agsm file to something else and edit the copy.

Comment: Hi, I used named instead of agsm and this provided a simple answer for me. Thank you for your help!

Comment: To locate the file`agsm.bst`, type `kpsewhich agsm.bst` at a command prompt in a terminal window.

Answer (score 8):

I suggest you proceed as follows:

- Find the file `agsm.bst` in your TeX distribution. Make a copy of the file and call the copy, say, `agsmemph.bst`. (Don't edit an original file of your TeX distribution directly.)
- Open the file `agsmemph.bst` in your favorite text editor -- the one you use to edit your tex files will do fine.
- Do a global search and replacement of `et~al.` with `\emph{et~al.}`. There should be five such instances.
- Save the file `agsmemph.bst` either in the directory where your main tex file is located or in a directory that's searched by BibTeX. If you choose the latter option, be sure to also update the filename database of your TeX distribution appropriately.
- In your main tex file, change the argument of `\bibliographystyle` from `agsm` to `agsmemph` and perform a full recompile cycle -- LaTeX, BibTeX, LaTeX, LaTeX -- to fully propagate all changes.

Happy BibTeXing!

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@misc{abcd,
  author = "Anne Author and Bertha Buthor and Carla Cuthor and Doris Duthor",
  title  = "Thoughts",
  year   = 3001,
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{agsmemph} %  <-- 'agsmemph' is being used

\begin{document}
\citet{abcd}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```