# How to omit url, doi, and urldate fields while using the IEEEtran bibliography style?

Tags: bibtex, ieeetran

The `\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}` in my IEEE Overleaf template produces:

> [1]  D. C. Knill and A. Pouget, “The Bayesian brain: the role of
>   uncertainty in    neural    coding    and    computation ”Trends    in 
>   Neurosciences,vol.   27,   no.   12,   pp.   712–719,   Dec.   2004.
>   [Online]. Available: http://linkinghub.elsevier.com/retrieve/pii/S0166223604003352

but I want:

> [1] D. C. Knill and A. Pouget, “The Bayesian brain: the role of
>   uncertainty in neural coding and computation,” Trends in
>   Neurosciences, vol. 27, no. 12, pp. 712–719, Dec. 2004.

How can I get rid of the '[Online]' and 'Available:' strings, as well as of the contents of the `url` field itself?

I have synced my Zotero library with Overleaf to produce a .bib file.
Entries look as follows:

```
@article{knill_bayesian_2004,
        title = {The {Bayesian} brain: the role of uncertainty in 
        neural coding and computation},
        volume = {27},
        issn = {01662236},
        shorttitle = {The {Bayesian} brain},
        url =          
       {http://linkinghub.elsevier.com/retrieve/pii/S0166223604003352},
        doi = {10.1016/j.tins.2004.10.007},
        language = {en},
        number = {12},
        urldate = {2018-11-14TZ},
        journal = {Trends in Neurosciences},
        author = {Knill, David C. and Pouget, Alexandre},
        month = dec,
        year = {2004},
        pages = {712--719}
}
```

I use bibtex to generate the bibliography.

```
\bibliography{bibtex/bib/references_from_zotero.bib}
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
```

Does anyone know a better way than to manually remove the `url`, `doi`, and `urldate` from either Zotero or the resulting .bbl file?

I have tried to untick the 'Include URLS of paper articles in references'  box Zotero for Mac --> Preferences --> Cite and then resync with Overleaf. This didn't have an effect.

Comment: If you are using `natbib`, it is relatively hard to make even slight changes in the bibliography style.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the IEEEtran.bst has an in-built control system.

Add this to your bib:

```
@IEEEtranBSTCTL{IEEEexample:BSTcontrol,
CTLuse_url = "no",
}
```

and then compile your document like this (the definition is not needed if you are using a IEEE class):

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\makeatletter
\def\bstctlcite{\@ifnextchar[{\@bstctlcite}{\@bstctlcite[@auxout]}}
\def\@bstctlcite[#1]#2{%
 \@bsphack
 \@for\@citeb:=#2\do{%
 \edef\@citeb{\expandafter\@firstofone\@citeb}%
 \if@filesw\immediate\write\csname #1\endcsname{\string\citation{\@citeb}}\fi}%
 \@esphack}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\bstctlcite{IEEEexample:BSTcontrol}
\cite{knill_bayesian_2004}
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{test}

\end{document}
```

[image]

For more info check `\IEEEtran_bst_HOWTO.pdf`.

Comment: Support for `\bstctlcite` can also be added via the [`ieeetrantools`](https://ctan.org/pkg/ieeetrantools) package.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Look for IEEEtran.bst in your TeX distribution files. For Windows and MiKTeX 2.9, this would be C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\bibtex\bst\ieeetran. Make a backup copy of it and save it under different name (e.g., IEEEtranbak.bst). Open IEEEtran.bst (your LaTeX editor would work for that) and and look for `FUNCTION {default.is.use.url} { #1 }` and change it to `FUNCTION {default.is.use.url} { #0 }`

```
\begin{filecontents*}{sample.bib}
@article{knill,
    title = {The {Bayesian} brain: the role of uncertainty in 
        neural coding and computation},
    volume = {27},
    issn = {01662236},
    shorttitle = {The {Bayesian} brain},
    url =          
    {http://linkinghub.elsevier.com/retrieve/pii/S0166223604003352},
    doi = {10.1016/j.tins.2004.10.007},
    language = {en},
    number = {12},
    urldate = {2018-11-14TZ},
    journal = {Trends in Neurosciences},
    author = {Knill, David C. and Pouget, Alexandre},
    month = dec,
    year = {2004},
    pages = {712--719}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage[square, nonamebreak, sort&compress, comma, numbers]{natbib}

\begin{document}

\cite{knill}

\newpage
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{sample}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Note that this might have side effects for other entries where you do want to use urls, such as `misc`.

Comment: @Marijn. This will change the default behavior as to whether a url is to be included or not. If specific references must always use url, then its code in the .bst file must be changed accordingly.

Comment: Sorry, but suggesting to modify, say, `IEEEtran.bst` -- or *any* original file of the TeX distribution, for that matter -- is very poor advice. Making changes to an original file almost certainly violates the terms of the LaTeX license. But even if you don't care about legal niceties, you still should never apply changes to an original file: Original files get overwritten without warning whenever you update (a) the package the file belongs to or (b) your entire TeX distribution, say, from TeXLive2018 to TeXLive2019. That's why one should make a copy, rename the copy, and modify only the copy.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/353858/how-to-change-et-al-to-italic-font-in-citation-call-outs-with-agsm-bibliogr

In the previous link, you gave an advice to someone to modify a .bst file. What makes the modification of a copy of a file not a violation of terms of use while the modification of the original is?

Comment: While this kind of hack might work for locally compiled documents, it's kinda useless if you're submitting a paper for publication (like, for example, to an *IEEE Transactions* journal...) - They will want to use their original, unmodified copy.

Comment: @Al-MotasemAldaoudeyeh - in the answer given in the link you provided, I deliberately wrote "Don't edit an original file of your TeX distribution directly." This advice continues to hold. I did NOT tell the OP to modify the original file; instead, I suggested that the OP make a copy, rename the copy, and edit the copy. The terms of use of the LaTeX license prohibit modifying an original file; they do not prohibit modifying a renamed copy of a file.

Comment: @Al-MotasemAldaoudeyeh Related explanation about renaming: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/47360/187536